# MongoDB .find() method doesn't work in Kotlin, in KTOR framework

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, mongodb-query, ktor

I'm trying to use the `.find()` method with no arguments to return all the documents in my collection but it return `404 Not Found` error.

**Here's how the things is organized**

*In the interface for implementation (datasource)*:

```
suspend fun getAllUsers(): List<User>
```

---

*The "User" model*

```
@Serializable
data class User(
  val name: String,
  val password: String
)
```

---

*In the implementation of the interface (service)*

```
private val users = db.getCollection<User>("Users")
```

```
override suspend fun getAllUsers(): List<User> {
        return users.find().toList()
    }
```

---

*In the route*

```
val userDatabase = MongoDB().userDatabase
```

```
val userService = UserService(userDatabase)
```

```
get("user/get-users"){

            try {

                val users = userService.getAllUsers()

                call.respond(message = users, status = HttpStatusCode.OK)

            } catch (error: Exception) {

                call.respond(message = "An error occurred", status = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)

            }

        }
```

I already tried to change the `service` class to:

```
val emptyFilter = Filters.empty()

return users.find(emptyFilter).toList()
```

But it didn't work as well, it always return the `404 Not Found` error. I checked out all around the internet and i didn't find nothing similar to my error.

And i tried it to my other collection that i need to use the same method `.find()` to return all the documents but it didn't work too.

---

**I expect the result like this:**

```
[
    { 
        _id: "randomId",
        name: "user 1",
        password: "user_1_pw"
    },
    { 
         _id: "randomId",
        name: "user 2",
        password: "user_2_pw"
    }
]
```

Comment: If I understand, you get the 404 error when calling the `user/get-users` HTTP endpoint defined in your KTOR code ? Can you include an example of a failing curl request please ?

Comment: Does the MongoDB part work as expected?

Comment: @amanin thank your very much, i was coding all day long and didn't notice that i was writing wrong the http endpoint, just woke up and saw your comment and i decided to test it again, and when i saw the failing error, i noticed it... thank y'all

Answer (score 1):

---

## **Resolution**

I noticed that i just was writing wrong my `endpoint` on Postman. Silly error after a longday coding

correct http endpoint is `"user/get-users"` but i was writing `"users/get-users"`